# Drupal 8 - Show all articles from same author

Tags: drupal-8

I'm new to Drupal.

I added articles using the user 1 account and using another authenticated user. When I click on the author name, it shows me the status of the user.

How do I show all articles from the same author?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a drupal view

```
    /admin/structure/views/add
```

display all fields you like from the article and filter with author 
You can even exposed the filter

Comment: I know that method but I don't want to use views.

Comment: Let's say I have a blog with several authors/users who published articles and I want to display all articles from that author without using views nor taxonomy. Or do I need use taxonomy?

Comment: You should really try using Drupal views. They are crazy powerful for displaying related content.